# Modifying a Certain object in array of objects But objects with the same attrib name are all changing(React)

Tags: reactjs

[image: here is the sample]
**here is the function i use for modifying an object attribute name**

```
 const editText=(i,e)=>{
        setArrayList(arrayList.map((item,index)=>(index==i?{...item,name:e.target.value}:item)))
    }
```

**here is where i modify the array using input the function above fires up whenever a key up**

```
   <td className={item.isFinished?"finished taskName":"taskName"}>
    {!editingMode?item.name:<input onKeyUp={(e)=>edittext(index,e)}></input>}
  </td>
```

**The Problem is  if i have type the same attrib name of an object from the array while I'm typing that object name is changing too, just a note this is a to do list app and this function is for editing the name of pre existing tasks**

Comment: Does the typo (`edittext` vs `editText`) exist in your code as well?

Comment: edittext is just the passed prop for editText because they aren't on the same component

Comment: Also, is ArrayList and setArraylist from your useState hooks?

Comment: yup they are the [arrayList,setArrayList]=useState([])

Comment: here i posted a gif of what's happening

Comment: [We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: i tried doing it as the date with name but still not working

Comment: please share a demo of your code using [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)